# generate_series for Min and Max dates

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

Here's the very basic query that i want to accomplish in Greenplum Database (like postgresql 8.2.15).

The field create_date in table t is timestamp w/o time zone.
Could anyone point me to right query to accomplish this? Thanks.

```
select * from generate_series ((select EXTRACT (YEAR FROM MIN(t1.create_date)) from t1),(select EXTRACT (YEAR FROM MAX(t1.create_date)) from t1))
```

Its throwing error

```
ERROR:  function generate_series(double precision, double precision) does not exist
```

LINE 1: select * from generate_series ((select EXTRACT (YEAR FROM MI...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly cast arguments to integer:

```
select *
from generate_series (
    (select EXTRACT (YEAR FROM MIN(t1.create_date)) from t1)::int,
    (select EXTRACT (YEAR FROM MAX(t1.create_date)) from t1)::int
)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/3d905/2)</kbd>**